# Flicks when changing form. C#

Tags: c#

I have 5 group boxes and 18 picturebox in each groupbox. 
When I open the form it took a lot of time to load. How would I make it faster?

The codes below doesn't work.

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint |
     ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
     ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true)
```

and

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
get
{
    CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
    cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
    return cp;
}
}
```

Comment: Does it open and then take a long time to populate, or just a long time before it loads?

Comment: It's taking around 4 seconds before the form loads.

Comment: Id suggest then you load the form differently, as its obviously loading data in the form_load event, move it until the form has shown, and throw a wait box up while it sorts it out. Makes the user feel the system is faster when actually its just as slow

Comment: My form load is empty, could you please give me an example for the wait box?

Comment: Using WS_EX_COMPOSITED does not make it faster.  It makes it *slower* but less unattractive.  Standard mistake is not paying enough attention to the images you display.  The pixel format is a very big deal, only 32bppPArgb is fast and images never have that format.  And the size matters a lot, rescaling a large image to fit in a picturebox is an expensive operation that happens every single time the pb gets repainted.  Most noticeable when you first display the window.

Comment: For the wait box throw up a panel with the word wait on it. Hide it when you're done loading

Comment: @HansPassant in my case my picturebox doesn't have images at all. I have set it as transparent and I was just basing my images on the background

Comment: Everything I said applies to a BackgroundImage as well.  Especially since it is usually large and not often a fit for the form's client area.  Seeing it back in a PictureBox is not for free.

Comment: While Hans' advice is excellent as usual, clearly displaying 5x18 = 90 small pictureboxes can't take 4 seconds. The time is going somewhere else..!

Comment: @TaW where is it going then?
Hans Should I just change the picturebox and change it to label or button?

Comment: How could we know where is goes?? We don't know anything about your program.. Replacing the PBs by buttons will certainly be a good test to see if the time really goes into those PBs..